# mclapply conflict with vecLib

Tags: r, multithreading, mclapply, rparallel

I recently changed my R BLAS framework to vecLib, which ships with Mac.  After doing so, I had problems with the parallel package in R.  Here is an example:

```
library(parallel)
xx1<-matrix(runif(2*70),ncol=2)
mcl.test<-mclapply(1:2,function(i) sum(tcrossprod(xx1[,i])),mc.cores = 2)
mcl.test

[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL
```

This ([mclapply returns NULL randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20674538/mclapply-returns-null-randomly)) discussion says that mclapply may be returning NULL because of memory issues.  While a 70x70 matrix shouldn't cause memory issues (my workspace is otherwise empty, garbage collected), note that the problem goes away for a 60x60 matrix:

```
xx2<-matrix(runif(2*60),ncol=2)
mcl.test<-mclapply(1:2,function(i) sum(tcrossprod(xx2[,i])),mc.cores = 2)
mcl.test

[[1]]
[1] 754.1371

[[2]]
[1] 889.7769
```

I have no problem when `mc.cores=1`.  I also have no problem if I switch my BLAS back to the default.  Further, there is no problem when I use R from the terminal.  **What is the right way to make multithreaded R (via vecLib) work with mclapply outside the terminal?**

```
sessionInfo()

R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.3 tools_3.4.3
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to make this work was to force vecLib to use only one thread (see [this](https://statistics.berkeley.edu/computing/blas)), by setting the environment variable `export VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS=1`.  This was not totally satisfying, because the sum of threads used by BLAS and the cores used by `mclapply` could still be less than the total number of available cores.

Hence, I switched to openBLAS instead of vecLib.  It appears that openBLAS does not have this problem (though it may have in the past).  With openBLAS, it appears I can run something on many cores using `mclapply`, with each child process using multithreading as much as possible.